# MySQL search matching first digits long number

Tags: mysql

I need to search in a MySQL db to find out to which company a certain mobile number belongs to.

The db looks like this:

**COMPANY | AREA CODE | BLOCK**

Company1 **|** 2245     **|** 2245

Company2 **|** 24 **|** 452

Company3 **|** 145 **|** 45

Basically  I have a form where I insert the area code and the number. The problem is that the area code is a exact match while for the block a long number is given but the search must be done for the first digits of that number (those first digits vary in length so I cannot perform a search looking for a exact mach as with the area code).

Search looks like

**24 452**123456789

And outputs: Company2

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bloques
        WHERE (`area` LIKE '%".$query1."%') AND (`block` LIKE '%".$query2."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

That code shows no results because it looks for a block "452123456789" if I look for "452" work just fine but that is not what I need.

Thanks!

Comment: Your % at the beginning will return incorrect results as they will match any data with that number in it. You should only put it in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your query as below

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  bloques 
WHERE `area` LIKE '%24%' 
  AND '452123456789' LIKE CONCAT('%', `block`, '%')
```

Also for first matching numbers in block you don't need wild cards on both side you can simply write it as `CONCAT(block, '%')` and for area `area = '24'`

### [`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff7f41/1)